# MySQL - assigne new names in SELECT statement and order by that new names

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has a basic structure:

```
id | first_name | last_name | role_id
```

**role_id** is type of int and user can add new roles. I need to order by role name, not by role_id, but I want to avoid join. Is there a way to make **SELECT statement** where I could do something like this:

```
 SELECT users.*, (
    if(role_id = 1, roleName), 
    if(role_id = 2, roleName2),
    if(role_id = 3, roleName3))
    AS roleName )
ORDER BY roleName DESC
```

Comment: So you have a `roles` like table where the roles are stored and reference them by a foreign key and what to sort them by the role name (stored in the `roles` table) without actually accessing the `roles` table?

Comment: @Progman that is the case - avoid join if possible.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the `JOIN`? If you want to avoid the `JOIN` where should the role names come from?

Comment: I am caching roles (as they are not added often) so I have them on the backend.

Comment: Just do a join.  Or sort in your client that has the role names cached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
 SELECT *, 
    CASE role_id
      WHEN 1 THEN 'roleName1'
      WHEN 2 THEN 'roleName2'
      WHEN 3 THEN 'roleName3'
    END AS roleName
FROM users
ORDER BY roleName DESC
```

Or, if `role_id`s are integers from 1 to n, use [`ELT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_elt) function:

```
SELECT *, ELT(role_id, 'roleName1', 'roleName2', 'roleName3') AS roleName
FROM users
ORDER BY roleName DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)